# Why doesn't the road lose its thickness to the tyre?

Tags: friction, everyday-life, material-science

From this [source](https://youtu.be/sffRo1-_D8E?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61qDex7XslwNJ-xxxEFzMNV&t=641), on average a rubber tyre loses $2$ atoms thickness per revolution due to the friction with the road.

Do these atoms/molecules that were peeled off the tyre get absorbed by the road? Then would the road increase in thickness due to this? If so, why doesn't the road lose it's thickness to the tyre instead? Thus making the tyre increase in thickness over time...

[image]

Comment: When you use chalk on a black board does the chalk come away with a black streak on it? Is the chalk permanently bound to the board? I know these are not the same materials, but it does show that just because one material loses molecules to another surface does not mean it happens the other way, nor does absorption have to happen.

Comment: Wear of tires, asphalt and brakes has been identified as a major source of harmful fine dust (up to 70% of what car traffic produces) by the German Environmental Agency: https://www.sueddeutsche.de/auto/feinstaub-verkehr-bremsen-reifen-1.4427241 (in German)
So yeah, a lot of it ends up as airborne particles

Comment: When I was about 5 years old a common occurrence was that I fell while playing outside and ran home with a bloody knee that didn't appear to have any skin left on it. Even then, through tears in my eyes, I wondered where on earth all the skin had ended up :-).

Comment: Where are you where the roads never wear out?

Comment: Yes also, but which is harder: vulcanized rubber or asphalt?

Comment: If you look at centuries old stone stairs in Europe it is common to see a double indent shape worn by foot traffic. In the stairwell of the Leaning Tower of Pizza the stair indentations have been filled with some protective substance (possibly many times) and are on their way once more to being warn into a double indent. I'd doubt that you'd end up with stair dust coatings on the bottom of your shoes.

Comment: In any location where it rains fairly often, the tyre debris and the road debris both get  washed off the road and down the drains. The road is damaged more by hydro-fracturing as tyres go over cracks full of water, than by tyre friction. And far more so by frost shattering, if such water-filled cracks ever freeze!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the hardness of the tire vs the road. Hardness is a measure of resistance to wear and the material of a paved road is generally harder than the material of a tire. So the tire will wear before the road with a net transfer of material from the tire to the road.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess the followup question would be "why don't roads leading into intersections get coated in rubber all the time"...

Comment: @John Dvorak I edited that out since it wasn’t relevant

Comment: The followup still holds, though...

Comment: @John Dvorak maybe they would if it were not for eroding factors such as rain. But are you saying tire material is not deposited on the road surface. Just trying to understand your point

Comment: I understand that tires wear out due to friction, I'm just pondering where that material ends up eventually.

Comment: @John Dvorak it ends up on the road surface as well as probably particles blown about in the air. You can most readily see evidence of it ending up on the white  surfaces of older concrete roads such as those used in the US interstate highway system. There are photos on the internet

Comment: Ahh right! I guess that's the reason we have diamond saws as diamond is hard to scratch... Looks some of the material ends up eventually in our lungs like all other pollutants ;) Also pretty sure the road has to lose material to tire because friction acts on both surfaces..

Comment: @pooja I suppose some road material could wind up on the tire, but that would depend on the road material. Probably not for concrete, but concrete is a lot harder than say asphalt. And the surface of asphalt on a hot summer day would probably be even softer. But you see relatively little evidence of road material building up on tires, with the exception of sand an small pebbles that get trapped in the treads, and perhaps a thin white layer of dust from loose surface material. Overall though, way more tire polymer material will wind up on the road than road material on the tire due to friction.

Comment: One rather dramatic example I'd give is the touchdown area at the end of an airport runway - it rather nicely illustrates the difference in hardness between the tire and the surface, courtesy of the black marks left there by landing aircraft.

Comment: -1 this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz So much material gets transferred here that airports have to go out and [remove it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfield_rubber_removal) occasionally.

Answer (score 109):

Anyone who has lived near a major thoroughfare knows that tire wear creates rubber dust that gets spread around everywhere. In some parts of Los Angeles, the residents have to hose off the sidewalks every day or so in order to prevent that dust from being tracked into their homes. Some of it also gets friction-welded into the surface of the road itself, leaving skid marks that are plainly visible.

Road surfaces themselves also lose material to the passage of tires. On concrete roads, the tire scrubbing action rubs away the mortar between the pebbles and after a while the pebbles become unsupported, and they too become dislodged.

The road material does not end up accumulating on the tire surface because the tire surface is being continually worn away. Any road material that might get embedded in it is thereby shed loose along with the tire dross.

Comment: Don't know how the other answer got accepted. This comes much closer. Fact is, reality is far more complex than the question's author implies. Wear occurs on _both_ the tires and the road. The road may temporarily gain some thickness, but it also loses material from the wear, and the rubber and other particles that settle onto the road are washed/rubbed away over time. Eventually, both tire and rubber wind up in the watershed, and both lose material and thickness.

Comment: Case in point: a decade or so ago, the concrete of I-80 west of Donner Summit (California Sierra Nevada) was so badly worn by traffic that the ruts in the right lane were deep enough to high-center my Honda Insght.  And almost any heavily-used road will begin to show obvious wear patterns after a couple of years.

Comment: I think a great example for this is Formula 1. Tires there (partly intentionally) degrade very fast, leaving a lot of discarded rubber outside of the racing line. You can see it clearly on these pics: http://f1.imgci.com/PICTURES/CMS/14200/14261.jpg, https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C1AglpDXAAALTyr.jpg.  They actually drive over them on the cooldown lap after the race, to make sure they comply with the minimum weight regulations: https://3legs4wheels.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/max-verstappen-austria-2019-parc-ferme.jpg

Comment: Those black patches that form on the road where many heavy cars are braking, are not skid marks, and afaik have nothing to do with the rubber of the tires. It's the asphalt in the road surface that gets moved to the top of the road by the turning force on the stones in the asphalt. Sorry, I cannot cite a source for this right now, but if you look closely at those spots, you can easily see that they are not made of tire rubber.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sure, it goes both ways - but the erosion due to tire friction is a tiny part of how roads get damaged. Weight loading, freeze cycles, heat expansion... all of that does far more damage than the miniscule scraping of tyres on road - and even that is probably dominated by pebbles stuck on the tyre, rather than the rubber itself.

Comment: @Luaan: that depends a lot on the composition of the road and what type of traffic is on it, but generally no, your claim's not correct. Many regions allow studded tires in the winter time, and these erode the roadway surface _very_ quickly. Large amounts of heavy truck traffic will also erode the roadway noticeably, over a span of 5-10 years, enough that the more-heavily traveled lanes are uncomfortable to drive on. In any case, the wear on the roadway, however minuscule, is greater than the amount of material _added_ to the roadway by tires, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: @cmaster I don't think that's true. These parts of rubber are not skid marks and are not released during braking, but mostly during high speed cornering. I couldn't find a source which would say this is anything but rubber. The F1 term for them is "marbles". https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/glossary.html  https://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2012/06/how-marbles-could-derail-an-f1-drivers-race/

Comment: @cmaster "*...when heated by lapping the track at racing speeds, the tyre surface is in a near molten state. Marbles are created as the car goes around corners, with the rubber squeezed towards the tyres' edge, resulting in small blobs of the rubber flying off.*"
However, there is also rubber getting laid down onto the track, example: https://rookief1.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/rubbering.jpg It is said that the track gets rubbered-in.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The studs aren't made out of rubber. They're essentially the equivalent of having sand/pebbles stuck in the tyre. Truck traffic does considerable damage to roads (there's the "weight per axle" thing), but why do you think that has to do with the tyres carrying away the road surface? The material added to the roadway is considerable, but it gets easily washed away by rain, wind and, well, other tyres.

Comment: @Luaan: _"why do you think that has to do with the tyres carrying away the road surface?"_ -- because the wear pattern. rutting in the portion of the roadway where the tires contact the surface, clearly indicates the wear is from tires.

Comment: @PeterDuniho How do you distinguish that from compactification? Especially in combination with cracks due to non-tyre-related wear? Every road damage analysis I've read attributes ruts to compaction. Do you have some reference that claims ruts are caused by road material being carried away as a result of erosion caused by tyres? In fact, the only damage I've seen mentioned to be caused directly by tyres wearing out the road is polishing - it makes the surface slippery. How often have you seen that on roads? E.g. http://iosrjournals.org/iosr-jestft/papers/vol9-issue12/Version-3/G091235359.pdf

Comment: Good answer, but I'd like to see the part about skid marks changing. [Skid marks aren't caused by rubber being deposited on the road surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skid_mark), they're actually caused by the tarmac itself being heated up.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, skid marks are generated on concrete roadways as well, where there is no tarmac to heat up.

Comment: @Luaan: If you have ever driven on a badly-worn concrete road, you may have noticed that the concrete has been worn down to the point where very large aggregate is exposed.  Compaction wouldn't do that, even assuming that concrete (unlike asphalt) even could be significantly compacted.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica: Not the case that skid marks are always, or even frequently, caused by heating tarmac.  As evidence, consider the black marks in the touchdown area of any airport with concrete runways (most commercial airports), where there IS no tarmac to be heated, but a lot of rubber being burned.

Comment: @Ardweaden I was not talking about the marbles that show up in F1 racing, I was talking about what niels nielsen called "skid marks", and which are not skid marks at all: Large dark patches on the tarmac where you cannot see a single stone, only plain black asphalt. I don't know the proper name for these, but they typically form where heavy trucks have a habit of braking hard. Like in front of some traffic lights. Those patches are quite dangerous, as they further reduce friction at places where cars already need a lot of friction regularly.

Comment: @cmaster, a closer inspection of the darkening which occurs at intersections will reveal that a major component of it consists of leaked motor oil which drips off the undercarriage under the influence of heavy braking. This darkening occurs in the center of the lane where there is almost no tire scrubbing action and the oil contained in it is responsible for the friction loss, especially when a film of water sits atop the oiled asphalt, and especially when you are on a motorcycle and are centered between the tire tracks on the left and right. .

Comment: Ok. In that case we are talking about four different phenomena here: 1) Skid marks (tracks left behind by skidding wheels), 2) marbles (rubber particles rubbed off the wheels in F1 racing), 3) oil stains (what you just described), and 4) those black patches of asphalt that I was talking about. I think, we really need better words to describe the later two...

Answer (score 8):

Others have noted that roads wear - an example of softer materials wearing harder one is liable to be useful.

If you look at centuries old stone stairs in Europe it is common to see a double indent shape worn by foot traffic. In the stairwell of the Leaning Tower of Pisa the stair indentations made by foot traffic have been filled with some protective substance (possibly many times) and are on their way once more to being worn into a double indent.

While both stairs and shoes wear, the rate of wear of the stone is no doubt such that the amount worn off in a climb is minimal - I'd doubt that you'd end up with a visible amount of stair dust coatings on the bottom of your shoes.

I took this picture in the 'Leaning Tower' in July 2003. You can see both the wear patterns in the stone and the added protective material:

[image: wear patterns in stone steps]

Detailed crop. [Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjAbK.jpg)

[image: cropped image of wear patterns in stone steps]

Comment: "clicking the larger photo gives a better overall impression" - Impression, heh. Nothing clickable though.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Larger image link added. They expire after a while.

Answer (score 4):

Both the tire and the pavement wear from the contact between the two.  The road will take significantly more damage if the tire has rocks stuck in the treads, but even in a "pure system" of perfectly clean rubber tires, the road suffers erosion just like everything else.

The folks who commented on the hardness or density of the pavement are right, but they left out the part where silk can be used to sand hardwood.  It may take a really long time to make a visible dent in the harder surface, but your inability to perceive something doesn't make it nonexistent.

Comment: Do you have a reference for `silk can be used to sand hardwood`? I wouldn't be too surprised to see that silk can be used as an abrasive (it's rather strong, and it could certainly be hard enough to sand mere wood), but I couldn't find any examples. We did easily cut wood with both cotton and silk threads, but that's not exactly surprising either - both _are_ harder than wood. Not that I'm saying the hard part doesn't suffer damage from the soft part; after all, you still need to sharpen your knives even if you're only ever cutting carrots or whatever :)

Comment: This. So much this. The assumption that the tires don't do anything to the road is simply false. See for example [this photo](https://www.rodeo.fi/media/377dc80e-8f96-40b8-949c-c7b0fd6b899a-tieurat). Our climate makes the problem much worse, for during the icy months (mid-November to mid-April) motorists are required, by law, to have seasonal high traction tires on the cars. More than half of us opt for studded tires, which are the only way to have a safe amount traction on ice (on snow a less drastic tire surface will do).

Comment: @Luaan Shortly after I posted this I did websearches for "silk to sand hardwood," since I figured I'd be asked for references.  There aren't any on the internet, or at least there aren't any I could find.  I don't know where I came across the information, but at some point in history silk was used as an ultra-fine sandpaper for hardwood weapons and furniture.  It's comparable to an 8000 or 12000 grit whetstone used to finish the cutting edge on a straight razor.  Sidenote that whetstones commonly dish out from use and have to be re-flattened.

Comment: I remember old roads made from stones - where you could see the stones surface getting polished - much like railways' rails getting polished and derusted from having trains roll over them frequently (up to a point where you can measure the amount of traffic that uses them

Answer (score 3):

Wheels sweep the road and the car creates enough wind to move most sizes of particles to the sides of the road. The rubber and road aren't comparatively adhesive enough to build up.

Sun and frost ( freeze thaw weathering ) are a lot more forceful than tyre contact.

Chemistry formulas may demonstrate that if the road grit's atomic bonds are a thousand times stronger than rubber, they will only wear out from impact with stones caught in tyres rather than the rubber itself.

Sharp bends in the road recieve a lot more physical force than straights and can wear multiple times faster.

Comment: hhttps://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/worn-stone-steps.html more examples. What sprang to my mind immediately was the entrance to the London pub "The Old Bank of England" but I couldn't find a photo (of what ~400 years of foot traffic does to a step).

Answer (score 1):

It can be the other way around too, it is dependent on the modulus of elasticity of the materials, if the road has higher modulus of rigidity then it will not break easily and a large amount of shear stress needs to be applied in order to do so , equal stress can cause different effects on different materials, According to IS:456 the modulus of concrete is 5000√(fck), MPa , where fck is the characteristic compressive strength of concrete whereas rubber has modulus of elasticity 0.0003GPa so when the two surfaces interact rubber loses more.
In regards to the other question, yes the thickness of road will increase but in a non uniform manner. Thanks and regards